# String contains returns false using lists

Tags: c#

Been trying to understand why this code is not working.
The Contains seems not to work using lists

```
var a = new List<string>() { "QHIDETH_1" };
var b = new List<string>() { "QHIDETH" };

var res = b.Where(x => a.Contains(x));
var res2 = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x));

Console.WriteLine(res.Count() + " " +res2.Count()+ " " + "QHIDETH_1".Contains("QHIDETH") );
```

The ouput is "0 0 True"

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwTkMH

Comment: Well, of course `Contains` works. Your list `a` does not contain the string "QHIDETH", and your list `b` does not contain the string "QHIDETH_1". You invoke the method `Contains` of a list here, which is not the same method/function as String.Contains`

Comment: `IEnumerable.Contains` DOES NOT MEAN `substring`. It means "does my collection contain this value verbetium?"

Answer (score 2):

Thats correct. The list a does not contain an element with value "QHIDETH". 
The list a does contain an element that is a string that contains "QHIDETH" (is a substring).

You are missing one level on the contains.

Change it to this code and it will work:

```
var res = b.Where(x => a.Any(elementOfA => elementOfA.Contains(x)));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `a.Contains(x)` you are searching the list `a` for a string that contains string `x` and they must match exactly. For partial matches which is what I think you are looking for you need to do

```
var res = b.Where(x => a.Any(y => y.Contains(x));
```